# How to fix `laravel recent daily log file has been deleted`

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use laravel 5.4 and daily logs for log error.
But sometimes the current log is deleted and laravel generates this error:`The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel-2019-09-06.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied` but the file has been already created.

I create manually the log file and put this permission `chmod 775 -R` to storage directory but it gets lost anyway.

Comment: How do you connect to your laravel application?

Comment: There's generally 2 instances where the `.log` files are created; an error/debug triggered by your web app, or an error/debug triggered by an artisan/cron/command line/etc command. These two cases have different users/groups that generate the file; `root` and `_www` (or similar, depending on your server). This is either a job for ACL (access control) or adding logic to generate the file and open permissions at the start of each day, etc.

Comment: @Wolfetto My laravel application serves a REST API and it gets called by http request.

Comment: @TimLewis i have already implemented a crontab for the creation of the log file each morning.

Comment: Then the file is going to be created with `root` (or whatever user is set to run the `CRON`) permissions, meaning an error/debug thrown from the web/REST API is going to cause that permission error.

Comment: @TimLewis the file is created by root user and it receives all permissions `chmod 777`

Comment: @TimLewis ok my user is `www-data www-data`, laravel generates the file with this user and it gets lost anyway.

i think the problem is not about permissions, but about the file that gets lost after its creation

Comment: Yeah, that part I don't really understand; daily `.log` files shouldn't be deleted until a certain number of them (30 by default, but configurable) exist and Laravel's automatic clean-up takes effect.

Comment: @TimLewis exactly, my configuration is 5 days.
and anyway laravel should delete only the old one

Comment: Yeah, that's true; it would delete the oldest one. Hmm... Unfortunately beyond the group/permissions thing, I can't say I'm sure what's up.

Comment: @TimLewis so are we both stack?

Comment: the log file will be created automatically if the right permissions is setup

Comment: And so far we all agree, but first the file is always created after it has generated these errors, but then it is deleted again and so that's why it generates infinite errors loop.

Comment: `failed to open stream: Permission denied` doesn't mean that the file has been deleted.

Comment: I understand that you stopped on the error, but this error is generated because the system tries to write to a file that does not exist.
I advise you to relate the whole discussion and if after understanding the problem you have a solution or suggestions I will be happy to try them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question about `https://laracasts.com`and we were able to solve the problem.

Find the solution here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-fix-laravel-recent-daily-log-file-has-been-deleted

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your operating system is Linux. I use Linux fedora and already had a similar error. What worked for me was to delete the logs folder, I used chmod 777 -R / folder name.
Give a clean because usually some garbage is stored. Use:
php artisan config: clear

php artisan confi: cache

php artisan route: clear

php artisan view: clear

and finally use: Composer install and then Composer update.

I believe this will solve !!

Comment: Yes my operating system is linux and I've already tried this step, thanks